# PreOrder Iterativo - Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, algoritmo

Tenho uma função que percorre a BST (*binary search tree)* em pré-ordem de forma recursiva. A função é a seguinte:

```
public Iterable<Key> preOrder() 
    {
        Queue<Key> queue = new Queue<Key>();
        preOrder(queue,root);
        return queue;
    }

    //Criação do método para a verificação pretendida. Método recursivo
    private void preOrder(Queue<Key> queue,Node node)
    {
        if(node != null)
        {
            queue.enqueue(node.key); //Visitar o nó
            preOrder(queue,node.left); //Visitar a sub-árvore esquerda
            preOrder(queue,node.right); //Visitar a sub-árvore direita
        }
    }
```

Estou a tentar perceber como fazer a versão iterativa dessa função mas nunca consigo chegar a nenhuma conclusão. Quando nesta parte do código

```
preOrder(queue,node.left); //Visitar a sub-árvore esquerda
preOrder(queue,node.right); //Visitar a sub-árvore direita
```

Tento escrever algo deste género:

```
queue.enqueue(node.left);
queue.enqueue(node.right);
```

O IDE avisa-me (com erro inclusive) que estou a entrar em conflito de tipos.

Se alguém me conseguir ajudar a perceber a resolução desta função de forma iterativa... estou a iniciar Java e fica bem confuso ainda.

ERRO IDE:

'Node não pode ser convertido para tipo Key'

Classe Node

```
private class Node {
        private Key key;           // sorted by key
        private Value val;         // associated data
        private Node left, right;  // left and right subtrees
        private int size;          // number of nodes in subtree

        public Node(Key key, Value val, int size) {
            this.key = key;
            this.val = val;
            this.size = size;
        }
    }
```

Classe Queue

```
public class Queue<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {
    private Node<Item> first;    // beginning of queue
    private Node<Item> last;     // end of queue
    private int n;               // number of elements on queue

    // helper linked list class
    private static class Node<Item> {
        private Item item;
        private Node<Item> next;
    }
```

Comment: Adicione, se possivel, o erro que a IDE mostra tambem, se for um aviso, poste um print na pergunta.

Comment: Adicione a classe Node tambem, pois ela é o centro do problema. Tambem adicione a classe Queue.

Comment: Mas adicionar na função ou adicionar em geral na classe em que estou a trabalhar? 

Porque isto é fornecido pelo ensino e essas duas classes já são integradas no projeto  sobre o qual trabalhámos.

Comment: Não adicione imagem de codigo, adicione de forma textual, como fez com os outros.

Comment: Bem visto, obrigado!

Comment: Iterativo é resolvido como uma *Queue* utilizando um algoritmo BFS (Breadth First Search) e sem utilizar recursividade

Comment: Mas é a única forma de resolver o problema? Não consigo aproveitar alguma coisa do código que tenho desenvolvido para a recursividade, e transformar, de alguma forma, na sua versão iterativa?

Answer (score 0):

Parace que o problema é o seguinte,note que, na sua função original, você faz uma chamada `queue.enqueue(node.key)` mas para o método iterativo você está tentando fazer

```
queue.enqueue(node.left);
queue.enqueue(node.right);
```

Mas na sua classe `Node`, `left`e `right`são objetos do tipo `Node`e não do tipo `Key`, por isso você recebe o erro de conflito de tipos, o método `enqueue`espera um objeto do tipo `Key`. Tente fazer `queue.enqueue(node.left.key)`.